# Redirect template based on permalink rather than $wp_query

Tags: templates, search

I'm trying to separate out different templates which utilise WordPress' search (`s` query var) along with different post types.

**Situation 1:** Default WordPress search page (`search.php`). Example: *example.com?s=test*

**Situation 2:** Post type archive (`archive-{$post_type}.php`), with search and taxonomy query var filtering ability. Example: *example.com/questions?s=test&category=wordpress*

Situation 2 has a few different final templates based on what post type is being queried.

So far I've managed to get the above to work with a function similar to this:

```
function wpse_redirect_search_page_post_types( $template ) {
    global $wp_query;

    if ( $wp_query->is_search ) {
        if ( get_query_var( 'post_type' ) === 'question' ) {
            return locate_template( 'archive-question.php' );
        }
    }
    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'template_include', 'wpse_redirect_search_page_post_types' );
```

However I encountered an issue when attempting to filter the search results page with different post types. I've got a bunch of checkboxes to filter what post types to show on the search results page, and the moment I've got only one post type (eg *example.com?s=test&post_type=question*) it sets the template to `archive-question.php`.

In terms of the `$wp_query`, they're identical (barring query hash differences) for
*example.com?s=test&post_type=question*
and
*example.com/question?s=test&post_type=question*.

What's the best way to do a check for whether I'm intending to show the search or archive template? The only other way I know how to do this is access the url through `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, but I was hoping there was a more WordPress-centric way of checking what template it intends to use.

Final use-case goals:

- example.com/questions?s=test **(archive)**
- example.com/questions **(archive)**
- example.com/?s=test **(search)**
- example.com/?s=test&post_type=question **(search)**
- example.com/?s=test&post_type=question,answer **(search)**